# Dependency Injection and use of default constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, code-injection

I am trying to understand Dependency Injection concept.
Below is the  example I am trying  to debug.
Here I have created Customer class whose dependencies I have Injected  in his constructor 
Now when  i called `this.Iorder.GetOrderDetails();` in the `Index` method it is giving me error of `NullReferenceException` and asking to use `new` keyword to create an object to call the method. 
When  I moved this call `this.Iorder.GetOrderDetails();` to another method `GetCutomerDetails()` and call that method  in  Index Method  it works.

**Question**: I am not able to understand why `this.Iorder.GetOrderDetails()`  method call is not working in  `Index` method and  why it is working  in `GetCutomerDetails()`

```
public  interface IorderDetails
{
    void GetOrderDetails();
}

public class CustomerModel : IorderDetails
{
    public void GetOrderDetails() {}
}
```

Controller:

```
public class CustomerController: Controller
{
    private IorderDetails Iorder;

    //DI constructor  Injecting OrderDetails object 
    CustomerController(IorderDetails iorderObj)
    {
        if (iorderObj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("orderObj should not be null");

        this.Iorder = iorderObj;
    }
    //Default constructor  
    public CustomerController() { }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
       CustomerController objCustomer = new CustomerController(new CustomerModel());
       objCustomer.GetCutomerDetails();

       //Commented GetOrderDetails() method
       //this.Iorder.GetOrderDetails();            
       return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetCutomerDetails()
    {
        this.Iorder.GetOrderDetails();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean dependEncy injection?

Comment: What are you using to inject the IOrderDetails into the CustomerController class?

Comment: Remove default constructor, and you will see why your code not working in Index method

Comment: The `CustomerController` creates yet another instance of `CustomerController`, most probably this is just mistake or bad design.

Answer (score 2):

You have default constructor for `CustomerController`. When it is called, you don't assign anything to `Iorder`. So it is `null` in that case. After that in method `Index()` you try to execute method `GetOrderDetails()` using `Iorder`, which is null. This fails. When you create **another** instance of `CustomerController` inside method `Index()`, you can call `GetOrderDetails()` on that instance.

In general, using multiple constructors is not advised when combined with Dependency Injection. But when it is necessary, you should initialize all instance fields to something that works. This is called a local default. An excellent book on Dependency Injection patterns and anti-patterns is [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/). Also take a look at the blog of its author.